# Azure Service Fabric : How to find out if an Actor already exists

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

How can I find out if an Actor with a certain ActorId exists?

The ActorProxy is only for creating an Actor. If a non-existing Id is provided, and the Actor does not exist, a new Actor is created.

The standard ActorService can retrieve all Actors, but thats about it as far as I can see.

Comment: If an Actor is an invoice, and the invoice has been deleted and an old link is used to retrieve the invoice, the invoice will be recreated. But it will be empty. Or am I looking at Actors the wrong way?

Comment: If you dont use the StateManager on an Actor, will the Actor still be persisted? Or will it be removed from memory and the ActorId will be available again? I agree on the 'never delete, marke it as deleted'.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there's no simple way of doing this. Actors are meant to **abstract away the lifetime** of an object's instance. Just call one when you need it, and it will be there. So I'm not sure this is really needed.

That said, you could create another service method to iterate through all the actors on the server-side instead of pulling the entire list to the client, but if you have millions of actor instances, it won't be very efficient.

Alternatively, you could store a marker state during your actor's initialization, and query the state provider for it - at the expense of adding more state and replication overhead to your actor.

First, create a service interface:

```
public interface IActorServiceEx : IService
{
    Task<bool> ActorExists(ActorId actorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

Then, create a custom actor service that implements this interface:

```
internal class CustomActorService : ActorService, IActorServiceEx
{
    public CustomActorService(StatefulServiceContext context, ActorTypeInformation actorTypeInfo, Func<ActorBase> actorFactory = null, IActorStateProvider stateProvider = null, ActorServiceSettings settings = null) 
        : base(context, actorTypeInfo, actorFactory, stateProvider, settings)
    {
    }

    public async Task<bool> ActorExists(ActorId actorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        const int batchSize = 1000;
        ContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            var actors = await StateProvider.GetActorsAsync(batchSize, token, cancellationToken);
            if (actors.Items.Contains(actorId))
            {
                return true;
            }
            token = actors.ContinuationToken;
        } while (token != null);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or the alternate version using the marker:

```
internal class Actor1 : Actor, IActor1
{
    protected override async Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        await StateManager.TryAddStateAsync("Activated", true);
    }
}

internal class CustomActorService : ActorService, IActorServiceEx
{
    ...

    public Task<bool> ActorExists(ActorId actorId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return StateProvider.ContainsStateAsync(actorId, "Activated", cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Finally, use it in when registering your actor, e.g.:

```
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor1>((context, actorType) =>
    new CustomActorService(context, actorType,
    () => new Actor1())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

And to call this new service method:

```
var actorService = ActorServiceProxy.Create<IActorServiceEx>(serviceUri, actorId);

var exists = await actorService.ActorExists(actorId);
```

Comment: This is not going to work when using `ActorId.CreateRandom()`. You get a reference to a random partition and the `IActorStateProvider` sees only the actors in that partition.

I updated the answer so that it uses the same actor id both for creating the `IActorServiceEx` proxy and for checking whether it exists.

Comment: I believe this will always return the "Activated" true all the time